# sci-kit learn: ValueError: shapes (14,128) and (8970,2) not aligned: 128 (dim 1) != 8970 (dim 0)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, text-classification

I'm running a python NB classifier for text classification. I have two processes: one trains a NB the classifier and generates the model.The other uses the model to classify new data. 
I'm suing the joblib to do so and here is the code:

```
   clfr = joblib.load('model.pkl')  
   predictor = clfr.predict(X)
```

My problem is the what is the argument that I should pass to the predict function? I've looked at the documentation and I found them using this line:

```
print(clf_pf.predict([[-0.8, -1]]))
```

I honestly don't understand based on what I should choose the n_samples and n_features especially if this is a new process that doesn't contain any line related to training and fitting.

I tried passing array of text lines, array of vectorized text lines, single text line and vectorized string line or array. No thing worked. If I tried to pass numbers, but I got this error:

```
ValueError: shapes (14,128) and (8970,2) not aligned: 128 (dim 1) != 8970 (dim 0)
```

So, my question is how to use this trained model after loading it using joblib.load?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your training and test dataset are not of same dimension.

Comment: @Sagar Can you provide an example so I can understand what you mean, please?

Comment: Can you paste the model.pk1 if it's not a problem?

Comment: @Sagar paste it as a text will give an unreadable text; you can download it from here https://www.dropbox.com/s/w72z7d8cfyzxfe1/nbModel.pkl?dl=0

Comment: @Sagar If you just give me a reference to do that, I would be thankful

Comment: What is the shape or `X`, and the shape of `X_train`? (with `X_train` the `X` you used to train the model before storing it). Both datasets `X` and `X_train` need to have same number of features (same number of columns).